# Is it a good idea to make a second DC installation in a car with its negative separate from the car body?

Tags: wiring, automotive, negative

Normally in a car's DC installation the negative is on the car's body. Is it just to make it cheaper by not having to provide two wires everywhere, but just one and use the car body as negative, or is there another more important reason it is done that way?

I ask, because I want to make a secondary DC installation in the car, with another battery, different voltage, to be used for my electronics, computers, etc. The second installation will have a separate battery, but that battery will be charged off the main installation - not directly, but through a charge controller, basically a DC-to-DC converter with current limit, which will have separate positive and negative terminals for both input and output.

How do you recommend to wire the negative of this secondary DC circuit, should I keep it separate, isolated from the car body, or should I also connect its negative wire to the car body, so use a common ground for both installations?

Comment: Pretty solid ground. Both batteries should or will be grounded to chasis too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the grounds in one point or leave them separate. As long as the only common point between the two circuits is the isolated power supply you are free to do as you wish.

If OTOH you want to connect them somewhere (to use the car antenna or sth.) then you should carefully choose the connection point (or even points) to avoid ground loops and ground noise.

Comment: I got an an answer from the manufacturer: http://www.wattflyer.com/forums/showpost.php?p=797303&postcount=11 of the DC-DC converter that the grounds of both sides can not be connected together, so I'll have to keep them isolated. Maybe I'll isolate the car body from the primary circuit too, put thick negative wire to all car's devices and be completely sure nothing will make the grounds touch.

Comment: So this means that your converter is not in fact isolated and what's more it has a current sensing resistor in the ground path (so ground potentials will vary a little with the charging output current). As far as isolating your car is concerned I would rather isolate the secondary circuit and leave the primary as is.

Answer (score 3):

The battery negative being attached the the body is for a [common ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29).  If you add a second battery it would probably be best to add it's negative to the body as well.  If not you could have issue with a [floating ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground).  This can cause circuit noise and shocks/discharges.

- [Connecting Batteries in series/parallel](http://www.zbattery.com/Connecting-Batteries-in-Series-or-Parallel)

Comment: But the second battery will be connected to the main circuit using the "FMA PowerLab 8 V2" device, and normally it is not meant to be used with a common ground of input and output. I am wondering will it even operate correctly that way.

Comment: As long as the input and output sides are totally isolated from each other it shouldn't be an issue.  But if your second circuit isn't grounded with the first there could be a voltage potential difference between the two ground circuits.

Comment: Hook the device up as the instructions say.  The second battery ground should be connected to the car's ground though the negative on the power source side.

Comment: Matthew Whited: your second comment is contradictory in itself and contradictory to the first one. The instructions don't say to connect the negatives together, and if I connect both batteries to car's chassis, they won't be totally isolated from each other.

Comment: Not really.  With your question I was assuming you were creating a secondary circuit to do something like power an extra radio or something that you built totally on your own.  In your comment to me you pointed to a product that you purchased that you are using as some sort of auxiliary power.  The instructions for this device may contradict the grounding reason because it has the potential of connecting batteries in series.  If it does this the negative terminal of one of the batteries could really be a higher potential then ground.

Comment: "But if your second circuit isn't grounded with the first there could be a voltage potential difference between the two ground circuits"  There are voltage differences between different points in a *single* ground circuit.  Metal is not a perfect conductor and any currents flowing through (cars have large, spikey currents) will create voltage differences from one point to another.  Make sure this isn't going to cause problems if the two circuits share a ground path.  Generally, you want the grounds of different systems connected together at a single point, not two.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply multiple connections between the grounds.  I meant to imply that the grounds needed to have at least one connection.  While having a second grounding connection should just reduce the overall resistance on the ground.

Comment: Matthew, what if the secondary installation is not 12V, but for example 24V, 48V or even 96V? Here I got advice to absolutely separate the ground of the higher-voltage installation (although I would like to understand why): http://www.diyelectriccar.com/forums/showthread.php?t=56897 What is your comment on that?

Comment: From the second circuit that negative terminal you want to consider 0 volts would be attached to ground (this is import because you may want the 48v source being +/- 24 volts.)  Typically this would just be the lowest negative terminal if you are chaining batteries in series.

Comment: BTW, do you plan on charging all of these batteries from your car's alternator?  If so you may run into even more problems.

Comment: Matthew: yes, all those batteries will be (sometimes, partially) charged from the car's alternator. But not only, sometimes also solar, rectified mains, possibly other sources. Any specific problems with that you have in mind? Anyway it seems I will be making separate isolated ground. Maybe even isolate ground of everything in the car from the chassis.

Comment: @Matthew: "While having a second grounding connection should just reduce the overall resistance on the ground."  How is this different from "multiple connections between the grounds"?

Comment: @miernik: If you're charging both systems from the same alternator, you're going to have to connect them at some point.

Comment: endolith: they will be charged from the same alternator, but the second system never directly, but through a switched-mode DC-DC converter, so that would keep it isolated, no?